# Connect to Tor through socks in C#

Tags: socks, source-code

First of all, I want to say that I am new to programming and I love it very much, also I have a task to accomplish.

I try to accomplish a socket connection through Tor between server-client (send and receive a message a simple protocol) in C#. I managed to do it in Java  with this library SilverTunnel-NG and it works very good and I am happy but I can not find anything or think about how to do this in C#.

I checked some libraries which I found (mentalis.org) used and seems very good, also I found another library, which seem as good as those from mentalis.org, which is called [starksoft-aspen](https://github.com/bentonstark/starksoft-aspen) and I am bit confused what to choose and which library will do the thing I want to achieve.

Is it possible to check it and give me a direction or whatever? I want how to do my next steps with C# code Tor (server-client).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the library offered by Mentalis.org was originally written for .NET v1.0 and v1.1. (.NET is currently at v4.6.) It also looks like it hasn't been updated since 2007. This could mean it's no longer supported, so you'd have to take this into consideration with regards to how safe/secure you think the code is.

I would say Starksoft-aspen code would be a better choice for further investigation, simply because it's not 8 years old. If it turns out that this library doesn't do what you want, then I'd continue your search.

As a next step, I'd start looking at the code in Github in detail, and compare the available APIs to the ones you used in your Java code. (At a quick glance it would appear to provide APIs for SOCKS proxying.) Without asking you to provide more details about what you're trying to achieve, and without looking at what you've implemented in Java, it will be difficult for anyone to give you specific directions. (This isn't really the forum for doing that. And working out the details is part of the fun anyway, and the best way to learn!)